# C++ Windows Forms - Password Strength

Tags: c++, winforms

I've been following YouTube tutorials most of the day now and I think I've got the basic hang of forms. I'm aiming to create something like this below, which checks a users password and shows how strong it is:

[image]

This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

I'd like to know the basic theory behind how the top form works, specifically how I can take the user input of password in my form and just get it to print and update in realtime underneath below. I'm not quite sure what tool is used to do that, or for that matter what tool is used to create the colour changing box.

Any help or direction is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That's a LOT of questions in one go. I can possibly answer one or two of the "part questions", but since that will not be an acceptable answer, I'm not going to.

Comment: thanks for the reply though, if you have any idea what tool was used to display the Score that would help, do you think it could just be a normal text box? I'm looking up tutorials on YT hoping to find something similar

Answer (score 1):

Add a keyboardListener to your jtextfield. When a key is pressed get the text and do your stuff(figure out the strength, number of Uppercase etc)

Answer (score 1):

Is this win32 or mfc forms, or some other tech like Qt or wxWidgets?

In both cases you will want to handle messages from the edit field as text is changed in it. This message is the EN_CHANGE message. Handle that message and you can get the text from the edit field and send messages to the strength form to tell it to change its color and text.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler` (or similar) to the TextBox. When raised, do whatever analysis you need to do on the string and update the table below. The color changing box can be one of many implementations. It can be something as simple as a panel that changes its background with a `System::Windows::Forms::Label` positioned on top of it. It actually looks like that, as the text is not centered.